# Why is Vec::resize an unstable function?

Tags: rust

As stated in the documentation [Vec](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-beta/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) has to be stable in 1.0-beta. However, if I try to call resize I see the following error message:

> error: use of unstable library feature 'collections': matches collection reform specification; waiting for dust to settle

It can be easily reproduced, e.g. here: http://is.gd/IhEfEu

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    v.resize(10, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is an issue in the documentation.

The `stable` attribute can be applied to the crate, to the type or to individual functions, but in the documentation you cannot see the deprecation status of functions, only of types and crates.

If you go to [the source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/2f63e9c127ceff853f560a8a74f6d37c8ebad400/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L1081), you will see:

```
impl<T: Clone> Vec<T> {
    /// ...
    #[unstable(feature = "collections",
               reason = "matches collection reform specification; waiting for dust to settle")]
    pub fn resize(&mut self, new_len: usize, value: T) {
```

And, as you can see in this file, there are still a lot of unstable functions in this module.

Comment: See @shepmaster's answer, you can see the status as well as the reason in the documentation.

Comment: @SteveKlabnik: As one of the 8% of men (so about 8% of developers...) affected by color-blindness to some degree; any chance of the stability status of functions being indicated by something *more* than just color?

Comment: @MatthieuM.i see you've filed a bug already, so i'll just leave it at that :)

Comment: @SteveKlabnik: It was me who filed it (or both?). Actually I hadn't notice that those fancy bars were different colors until Shepmaster pointed it out.

Answer (score 3):

A function *can* be marked as unstable, and [`Vec::resize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize) is:

[image]

The yellow bar on the left indicates stability, and hovering over it describes why it is unstable.